# Send-MailMessage multiple parsing variable

Tags: email, powershell

I want to `Send-MailMessage` with PowerShell to multiple users.
This works:

```
Send-MailMessage -To "test@mail.fr", "test2@mail.fr" -Subject "TEST BASE INCIDENT SCRIPT" -Body "TEST" -SmtpServer $emailSMTP -BodyAsHtml -Credential $emailCredential -Encoding $emailEncoding
```

I have a variable `$email` I had construct like this:

```
$email = ''
$c = 0
foreach ($currentValue in $value) {
    $id = $currentValue.LookupId
    $spUserManager = $spweb.AllUsers.GetByID($id)
    if ($c -gt 0) {
        $email += ","+($spUserManager.Name + " <" + $spUserManager.Email + ">") 
    } else {
        $email += ($spUserManager.Name + " <" + $spUserManager.Email + ">") 
    }
    $c++
}
```

But when I replace `-To` with my variable `$email`, it dosen't work. (no error, just send to the first user in `$email`).

```
Send-MailMessage -To $email -Subject "TEST BASE INCIDENT SCRIPT" -Body "TEST" -SmtpServer $emailSMTP -BodyAsHtml -Credential $emailCredential -Encoding $emailEncoding
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Send-MailMessage](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx) or [ss64](http://ss64.com/ps/send-mailmessage.html)

`-To<String[]>` Specifies the addresses to which the mail is sent. Enter names (optional) and the e-mail address, such as "Name ". This parameter is required.

Example:

```
send-mailmessage -from "..." -to "User02 <user02@example.com>", "User03 <user03@example.com>" -subject ...
```

> This command sends an e-mail message with an attachment from User01 to
>   two other users.

**I mean you need to use `,` separator to send e-mail to few users.**

```
correct "User02 <user02@example.com>", "User03 <user03@example.com>"
wrong "User02 <user02@example.com> , User03 <user03@example.com>"
```

Answer (score 0):

As [@MrDywar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32519795/1630171) already pointed out you're constructing `$email` as a single comma-separated string:

```
"test <test@mail.fr>,test2 <test2@mail.fr>"
```

when it needs to be a list of strings:

```
"test <test@mail.fr>", "test2 <test2@mail.fr>"
```

This should produce the desired result:

```
$email = foreach ($currentValue in $value) {
    $spUserManager = $spweb.AllUsers.GetByID($currentValue.LookupId)
    $spUserManager.Name + " <" + $spUserManager.Email + ">"
}

Send-MailMessage -To $email -Subject ...
```